# Can't make text-area resizable to fit windows size

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to make a text-area resizable with this code:

```
<div class="fields" style="resize:both;">
  <div class="text-area-display-panel" style="resize:both;">
    ...contents...
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it's not working, and I can't find out why (it should be that simple, right?). Besides, is there any CSS property or similar to make the window always fit the window size?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: where is your text-area tag??

Comment: Could you set up [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your code? It would help a lot!

Comment: Why not use the html `<textarea>` tag that is re sizable by default http://jsfiddle.net/ctvzkbp0/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `resize` property has no effect when `overflow` is set to `visible` (which is the default value).

Try this:

```
<div class="text-area-display-panel" style="resize:both; overflow: hidden;">
```

Details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize

Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/resize.html

Comment: You're a boss mate! Many thanks for it, it's working now. I've tried a lot of changes but I didn't know it won't work with visible overflow. Do you know if is there any possibility to make it always fit the screen? (I mean, the area makes itself bigger when the window does, and the same for smaller)

Comment: Depends on your layout. `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0` could be an option. If this doesn’t work for you, I recommend to post a separate question with more details regarding your desired layout and/or a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an html element to always fit the window size one of the best ways to do it is in the css, put its width and height to 100%. Make sure you have the percent sign.

```
.text-area-display-panel {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Also the problem might be you do not have a color assigned to the div so you can not see it. If so then just add a background-color property.